# String interpolation in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

I want to write the code that will output :

```
length [1,2,3] => 3
```

In Ruby, I could do it like :

```
puts "length [1,2,3] => #{[1,2,3].length}"
```

Following try is Haskell failed...

```
Prelude Data.List> print "length [1,2,3]"
"length [1,2,3]"
Prelude Data.List> print (length [1,2,3])
3
Prelude Data.List> print "length [1,2,3]" (length [1,2,3])

<interactive>:1:0:
  Couldn't match expected type `Int -> t'
     against inferred type `IO ()'
 In the expression: print "length [1,2,3]" (length [1, 2, 3])
 In the definition of `it':
      it = print "length [1,2,3]" (length [1, 2, 3])
 Prelude Data.List>
```

Comment: BTW, using print on a string will print it with quotes (and escaped). Try putStr or putStrLn to print the string as-is.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Strings are really just lists. So you can convert the number returned from length and append it to your other string with normal list functions:

```
print $ "length [1,2,3] " ++ show (length [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 43):

You can also just use [`Text.Printf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Text-Printf.html) which is included in the GHC base libraries:

```
> let format s = printf "length %s => %d\n" (show s) (length s)
> format [1,2,3]
length [1,2,3] => 3
```

There are several string interpolation packages on Hackage http://hackage.haskell.org if you want fancier situations.

Answer (score 36):

While the other posters here mention many of the 'right' ways to do string interpolation, there is a fancier way using quasiquotation and the [interpolatedstring-perl6 library:](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/interpolatedstring-perl6/0.4/doc/html/Text-InterpolatedString-Perl6.html)

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

import Text.InterpolatedString.Perl6 (qq)

main = putStrLn [$qq| length [1,2,3] => ${length [1,2,3]} |]
```

In fact there is also an [interpolatedstring-qq](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/interpolatedstring-qq/0.1/doc/html/Text-InterpolatedString-QQ.html) library which offers a Ruby syntax.

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

import Text.InterpolatedString.QQ (istr)

main = putStrLn [$istr| length [1,2,3] => #{length [1,2,3]} |]
```

That said, you probably should just use show and ++ or concat to glue together the strings

```
main = putStrLn $ "length [1,2,3] => " ++ show (length [1,2,3])
```

or

```
main = putStrLn $ concat ["length [1,2,3] => ", show $ length (1,2,3)]
```

The latter tends to look nicer, code-wise, when you are gluing together a lot of string fragments.

Comment: Why is it better to use `concat` or `++` than QuasiQuotes?

Comment: Every time you use template-haskell your compiler has to load up at compile time all of your dependencies. It can be quite slow. I tend not to incur that cost for a trivial convenience like string interpolation, when the alternative is almost the same length, and unlikely to require me to completely refactor my code when the quasiquotation which approximates Haskell syntax that I'm using can't parse some syntactic construct I need.

Comment: @VladtheImpala, another reason is that each QuasiQuoter requires the reader to understand a new language, so they won't necessarily be able to see bugs straight away. I'd only use a QuasiQuoter if my project used it a lot, and so I can expect developers to know how it works.

Comment: Instead of `concat` you can use `intercalate`, so you can avoid manually inserting the separating spaces:
`main = putStrLn $ intercalate " " ["length [1,2,3] =>", show $ length (1,2,3)]`

Answer (score 9):

Use [*format*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-format-simple-1.1.0/docs/Text-Format.html) function from [*text-format-simple*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-format-simple) library:

```
import Text.Format
format "length [1,2,3] => {0}" [show $ length [1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this in ghci:

```
Prelude> :t print
print :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

As you can see, the `print` function accepts only one argument, while the code above supplied two.

Instead, try this:

```
putStrLn ("length [1,2,3] => " ++ show (length [1,2,3]))
```

It's joining the two strings with `++` and then prints it.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to what others said you can also use the monadic bind operator `>>` to combine the two IO actions:

```
putStr "length [1,2,3]: " >> print (length [1,2,3])
```

This is equivalent to combining them with do-notation:

```
do putStr "length [1,2,3]: "
   print (length [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like

```
putStr "length [1,2,3] => "
print (length [1,2,3])
```

EDIT:

If you want to do it like a function, to pass any list and write its length, you could do it this way:

```
print_length :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
print_length xs = print ("length " ++ show xs ++ " => " ++ show (length xs))

Main> print_length [1,2,3,4,5]
"length [1,2,3,4,5] => 5"

Main> print_length []
"length [] => 0"
```

Of course, as commented above, you could use `putStrLn` instead of print.

Comment: Is three any way write them in one line?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to debug stuff like:

```
inc :: Int -> Int
inc x = [debug|1+x|]

inc 2
-- prints "1+x = 3"
-- returns 3
```

this QuasiQuoter might help:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Template where
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
import Language.Haskell.Meta.Parse
import Debug.Trace

-- | e.g. f x = [debug|1+x|]
debug :: QuasiQuoter
debug = QuasiQuoter traceExp undefined undefined undefined

-- | e.g. traceExp "1+x"  ->  [| trace "1+x = $([|1+x|])" (1+x) |]
--   (or something)
traceExp :: String -> Q Exp
traceExp s = [|( trace $(showExp s) $(parseE s) )|]

-- | e.g. showExp "1+x"  ->  [| "1+x" ++ " = " ++ show (1+x) |]
showExp :: String -> Q Exp
showExp s = [|( $(stringE s) ++ " = " ++ show $(parseE s) )|]

-- | e.g. parseE "1+x"  ->  (UInfixE (LitE (IntegerL 1)) (VarE +) (VarE x))
parseE :: String -> Q Exp
parseE = return . either (const undefined) id . parseExp

-- $ cabal install haskell-src-exts
-- $ cabal install haskell-src-meta
```

the variables are captured dynamically. I had written it while learning Template Haskell, but `debug` does work for debugging stuff during development.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted about [`fmt`](https://github.com/aelve/fmt) formatting library recently in [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43306215/2900502). With this library you can write interpolation like this:

```
> "There are "+|n|+" million bicycles in "+|city|+"."
```

Though, you might be also interested in some TH library with Quasi Quoters:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/interpolate-0.1.1/docs/Data-String-Interpolate.html

Though, this library is very slow in comparison with `fmt`.