# String formatting in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

What is Haskell's equivalent of

```
string str = string.Format("{0} {1}",10,20); // C#
```

Comment: How to do `{0, 10}`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is a [Printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Text-Printf.html) module in GHC.

```
import Text.Printf
str :: String
str = printf "%d %d" 10 20
```

however it is probably simpler to just do

```
str = show 10 ++ " " ++ show 20
```

Comment: Its not working I got `ERROR filename.hs:3:Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding`. I am using WinHugs.

Comment: You should switch to GHC. Hugs is unmaintained, slow, and supports very few of the packages on Hackage. It isn't part of the Haskell Platform specification either.

Comment: `Text.Printf.printf` returns an IO action (`IO ()`) when fully applied, not a `String`.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake: It also returns `String`. It can return any type that is `PrintfType`.

Comment: anything like python's f-string?

Comment: This answer does not work for me: `Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘printf’ prevents the constraint ‘(Text.Printf.PrintfArg t0)’ from being solved`.

Answer (score 30):

You could use the `format` function provided by the [text-format-simple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-format-simple) package:

```
import Text.Format
format "{0} {1}" [show 10, show 20]
```

This function has the signature:

```
format :: String -> [String] -> String
```

So all you need is provide your parameters as strings.
Another example:

```
format "Some {0} believes that 1 + 1 = {1}." ["people",show 10]
```

Comment: I'd recommend /not/ using that package, as it's very constrained in what it can do. I'm working on a package named [text-format](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-format) which is generally more capable, and already quite usable for this purpose.

Comment: Dmitry, all the packages you listed save for double-conversion are included in the Haskell Platform. The vast majority of users won't have to install that much. You argument is still valid though.

Comment: @BryanO'Sullivan Thanks for the pointer.  I've had a look at your package, and while it looks much more useful than the alternatives (and has a type for the format specifier rather than plain string, which seems like an extremely good idea) unfortunately for me it produces `Data.Text` as its output, rather than `String`.  As I need to integrate with existing code that relies on `String`, this would require an unnecessary conversion for me.  Is there an alternative that produces a `String` output and supports a format specifier that allows you to change the order of fields in the output?

Answer (score 14):

Putting answer here in case somebody searching for formatting libraries in *Haskell* on StackOverflow. There's type-safe and fast formatting library called [`fmt`](https://github.com/aelve/fmt) now. With it you can write code like this:

```
> "There are "+|n|+" million bicycles in "+|city|+"."
```

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
printf "%d %d" 10 20
```

See [`Text.Printf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Printf.html).

Comment: This answer does not work for me: `Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘printf’ prevents the constraint ‘(Text.Printf.PrintfArg t0)’ from being solved`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could write

```
unwords [show 10, show 20]
```

or even

```
unwords (map show [10, 20])
```